# Stuck in a redirect loop

Tags: c#, redirect

I have a block of code in the base controller that I want to redirect to a page, if the user's status is 0.

```
if (UserService.IsLoggedIn())
{
    model.IsLoggedIn = true;
    model.CurrentUser = UserService.GetCurrentUser();
    model.UserProfile = svc.GetByUserId(model.CurrentUser.Id);
    if (model.UserProfile.OnboardStatus == 0)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/user/onboard/"+ model.UserProfile.Id);
    }
}
```

I'm stuck in a redirect loop, and I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: What route is this controller code associated with?

Comment: Is the UserController based on the base controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are inheriting `UserController` also from `BaseController`.

**Solution 1**: Don't inherit `UserController` from `BaseController`.

**Solution 2**:

I presume that you are having this part of code in your `OnActionExecuting` in `BaseController`.

If so you can update you code as below.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
        if (UserService.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            model.IsLoggedIn = true;
            model.CurrentUser = UserService.GetCurrentUser();
            model.UserProfile = svc.GetByUserId(model.CurrentUser.Id);
            var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower();
            var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower();
            if (controllerName != "user" && actionName != "onboard" && model.UserProfile.OnboardStatus == 0)
            {
                HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/user/onboard/"+ model.UserProfile.Id);
                }
            }
}
```